# Play Framework as Service inside a scala application

Tags: scala, playframework

i have a little problem. I have to create a scala application. This application have to do some stuff. Create threads and other stuff. That isnt important for this question.

But to interact with this application it is neccessary to create a webinterface. I would like to create this interface by play.
The problem is, i have to integrate the play application inside my normal application. As component. And in the same moment as the application is runnig, he has to start also the play component. And if this worker is fail sometime, to restart it.

Is that possible? And if yes which way you would suggest.

Comment: By the way, have a look at [spray](http://spray.io/). _"spray is an open-source toolkit for building REST/HTTP-based integration layers on top of Scala and Akka. Being asynchronous, actor-based, fast, lightweight, modular and testable it's a great way to connect your Scala applications to the world."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke your normal application when play framework is starting. (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal) More specifically, onStart method in global object may be right place where you call your normal codes.

```
import play.api._

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  val yourInstance = new YourInstance()
  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    yourInstance.start()
  }
}
```

Additionally, you can change your thread model to actor model. (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAkka)

Comment: Great thanks. This means that my application have to be an Play Application. And this needs to import my other application? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think it is easy way.

Comment: But with this way I only have the ressource of the started play application. Do I not? And if yes a complex application could run out of memory. Whats about the way to build a play framework jar and start through the main application. Do you think their is a good way?